# Rest api to get all document where checked out is Yes and checked out by system account

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience

Is there any REST API to get list of all documents where Checkout is yes and checked out by system account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below REST query:

```
<site-url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,CheckoutUserId&$filter=(CheckoutUserId ne null and CheckoutUserId eq 10)
```

Replace `10` by user ID of your System Account.